Why did Sidney want Steve Dallas to get his job back?
Newspaper columnist J.J took the help of press agent Sidney to plant a
smear on Steve Dallas, who is in a relationship with J.J’s daughter, leading
to Steve losing his job. Consequently, Sidney phoned J.J about Steve’s job loss:

J.J: Get him back his -You said get him back his job. For what?
Look, Sidney, I don't like this. This is traveling  in the dark.

Why did Sidney want Steve Dallas to get his job back?
